# how to only validate string length if checkbox is checked in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

on my system, users have the option to "upload a doc file", "write one now" or "dont use the doc file".

I would like to validate a strng minimum using data annotations to validate the text area of "write one now", however the validation can only be triggered if "write one now" is checked.

Can this be achieved using data annotations or only with javascript?

Comment: How are the options presented - checkbox, radio button, select list???

Comment: hi mate, radio buttons.

Comment: Raddio buttons can have a separate value from what is displayed i.e. <input type-'radio' value='1'>upload a doc file or <input type='radio' value='upload'>upload a doc file, <input type-'radio' value='write'>write one now. This way you only need to check for a number or a single word.

Comment: yes, that is correct. So my goal is to only validate the textbox for a minimum length using the data annotations if the radio "write one now" is selected. I cannot trigger an error saying that a minimum of x characters is required when they want to upload a file.

Comment: You have to resort to manual JavaScript here. Automatic validation (via DataAnnotation) won't cut it

Comment: so I know we can compare two text boxes with the Compare annotation, but there is nothing that would allow me to compare to a boolean or a specific value string?

Comment: @Mrchief, thanks for that - I completely missed the C# tag.

Comment: Not unless you roll your own custom validator.

Comment: @all downvoters, what is the issue with my solutions? post that, let  me know, istead of marking as dowwnvote.

Comment: @WPalombini, have you tried my solution, i think, that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have one suggestion for this, use radio buttons to let user select only one, on clicking that, see if "write a row" is selected, then make the textbox or textarea as editable/ user can enter text , else let that textarea remain "Readonly". I have used this code, it is working.

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rad1" runat="server" Text="upload a doc file" GroupName="vald" onchange="Check();"/>
<asp:RadioButton ID="rad2" runat="server" Text="write one now" GroupName="vald" onchange="Check();"/>
<asp:RadioButton ID="rad3" runat="server" Text="dont use the doc file" GroupName="vald" onchange="Check();"/>

<asp:TextBox TextMode="MultiLine" ID="txt" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"/>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function Check()
    {
        if (document.getElementById("rad2").checked)
        {
            document.getElementById("txt").removeAttribute("readonly");
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("txt").readonly = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but I suggest that you read OP's question carefully. You've not answered his question so far.

Comment: hi @Arindam, yes, thanks for your help, I actually have done it already using javascript in a different way. All good. I wanted to use it through data annotations, I may try to create a custom one later on.